# React App working fine but still whenever I compile it says failed to compiler module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, create-react-app

Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\bytewise_Project#1\my-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\bytewise_Project#1\my-app'
ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\bytewise_Project#1\my-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\bytewise_Project#1\my-app'

webpack compiled with 1 error

I was expecting it would successfully compile without any errors but I am unable to understand why this error is coming. Although it is working fine and printing the required details on screen but on terminal it gives the above error.

Comment: We need more information, as it stands, this is nearly impossible to answer in a helpful way

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your node module file
2. `npm install`

Now run your project with `npm start`